# Applying function in only one element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm developing my own portfolio. I want put my projects in a Menu, like this [felipestoker.com](http://felipestoker.com)

Well, if you click in **Works** it works fine. Will appear a Menu with my works in categories. When I click in some categories, all of them appear. 
Look at this image:

[image]

And the result:

[image]

How can I fix it?

A piece of my code:

```js
$(".worksList h2").click(function() {
  $(".worksList ul").slideDown();
  $(".worksList i").removeClass("fa-plus-square-o");
  $(".worksList i").addClass("fa-minus-square-o");
});
```

```css
#works {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #474747;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  ;
  *display: none;
  */ z-index: 3;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#works span {
  font: 700 23px/23px"Open Sans";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.worksList h2 {
  font: 300 15px/30px"Open Sans";
  color: #d9cfcf;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
}
.worksList h2:hover {
  color: white;
}
.worksList h3 {
  font: 700 15px/30px"Open Sans";
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.float-left {
  float: left;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
}
.float-none {
  float: none;
}
.display-block {
  display: block
}
.display-inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
.display-table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
.display-none {
  display: none;
}
/*BACKGROUND*/

.background-white {
  background: #fff
}
.background-gray47 {
  background: #474747
}
```

```html
<div id="works"> <span class="worksClose cursor-pointer">X   Fechar</span>
  <span class="bar background-white margin-top-30 margin-bottom-30"></span>

  <div class="worksList">
    <!-- Séries -->
    <h2 class="text-align-center cursor-pointer">
  <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>
  Series
 </h2>
    <ul class="display-none">
      <li class="display-block grid_100p margin-top-10">
        <a class="display-inline-block" href="http://www.lilyhammer.com.br">
          <img class="float-left" src="./images/1.png" alt="Lilyhammer" title="Lilyhammer" width="30" height="30" />
          <h3 class="float-left margin-left-15">Lilyhammer</h3>
        </a>

      </li>
      <li class="display-block grid_100p margin-top-10">
        <a class="display-inline-block" href="http://www.punhodeferro.com.br">
          <img class="float-left" src="./images/1.png" alt="Punho de Ferro" title="Punho de Ferro" width="30" height="30" />
          <h3 class="float-left margin-left-15">Punho de Ferro</h3>
        </a>

      </li>
      <li class="display-block grid_100p margin-top-10">
        <a class="display-inline-block" href="http://www.westworld.com.br">
          <img class="float-left" src="./images/1.png" alt="West World" title="West World" width="30" height="30" />
          <h3 class="float-left margin-left-15">West World</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Menção Especial -->
    <h2 class="text-align-center cursor-pointer">
  <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>
  Special Mention
 </h2>
    <ul class="display-none">
      <li class="display-block grid_100p margin-top-10">
        <a class="display-inline-block" href="http://www.pulpfiction.com.br">
          <img class="float-left" src="./images/pulp.png" alt="Pulp Fiction Brasil" title="Pulp Fiction Brasil" width="30" height="30" />
          <h3 class="float-left margin-left-15">Pulp Fiction Brasil</h3>
        </a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need `.each()` and `.eq()` to target the proper *clicked* element like

```
$(".worksList h2").each(function (i) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $(".worksList ul").slideUp().eq(i).slideDown();
        $(".worksList").find("i").removeClass("fa-plus-square-o").eq(i).addClass("fa-minus-square-o");
    });
});
```

**Notice** I added `.slideUp()` so previous expanded elements will close when selecting a new one. This may need a bit of clean up

---

**EDIT**: the tweaked code so you can toggle the lists on each click

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".worksList h2").each(function (i) {
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var _this = $(this);
            var _parent = _this.parent(".worksList");
            var _sibling = _this.next("ul");
            if (_sibling.hasClass("expanded")) {
                _sibling.slideUp(function () {
                    _parent.find("i").addClass("fa-plus-square-o").removeClass("fa-minus-square-o");
                }).removeClass("expanded");
            } else {
                $(".worksList").find("ul").slideUp(function () {
                    $(".worksList").find("i").removeClass("fa-minus-square-o").addClass("fa-plus-square-o");
                }).removeClass("expanded").eq(i).slideDown(function () {
                    _parent.find("i").eq(i).removeClass("fa-plus-square-o").addClass("fa-minus-square-o");
                }).addClass("expanded");
            }
        })
    });
}); // ready
```

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

Comment: It almost worked perfectly! :D - When I click in `h2` the others `fa-plus-square-o` desapear. Can I put a **slideUp** afterwords?

Comment: hold tight ... I will tweak it ;)

Comment: I'm thinking to use `toggle`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$(".worksList").click(function() {
  $(this).find("h2 ul").slideDown();
   $(this).find("h2 i").removeClass("fa-plus-square-o").addClass("fa-minus-square-o");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, it looks like

```
$(".worksList h2").click(function() {
  $(".worksList ul").slideDown();
  $(".worksList i").removeClass("fa-plus-square-o");
  $(".worksList i").addClass("fa-minus-square-o");
});
```

Is targeting all ul's in .workList. That's why all lists are getting expanded on. Try making the event more specific, tied to that particular element, then target the next `ul` according to your code.

Such as:

```
$(".worksList h2").click(function() {
  $(this).next("ul").slideDown();
  ...
});
```

To be specific to each of the `h2` headings, you'll need to be able to specify "each" heading as well. So encapsulate the function like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".menu-title").each(function(i) {
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).next("ul").slideDown();
        });
    });
});
```

Then probably at some point, you'll want to be able to slideUp that menu as well.

A quicker way may be to use slideToggle like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".menu-title").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
               $(this).next("ul").slideToggle();
        });
    });
});
```

Then you'll want some logic to add/remove the different classes to the `i` icon. Below the code is comparing `if` clicked upon menu h2 has a `fa-plus-square-o` class icon, then removes that class and adds the `fa-minus-square-o` instead. If it doesn't, then `else` the `fa-minus-square-o` class is removed and replaced with the `fa-plus-square-o` class.

```
if ($(this).find("i").hasClass("fa-plus-square-o")) {
               $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-plus-square-o").addClass("fa-minus-square-o");
               } else {
                   $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-minus-square-o").addClass("fa-plus-square-o");
               }
```

Altogether, the code looks like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".menu-title").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).next("ul").slideToggle();
            if ($(this).find("i").hasClass("fa-plus-square-o")) {
              $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-plus-square-o").addClass("fa-minus-square-o");
            } else {
               $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-minus-square-o").addClass("fa-plus-square-o");
               }
        });
    });
});
```

And the jsFiddle to demo http://jsfiddle.net/63n4wyov/2/

Comment: Inside the function, replace $(".worksList ul").slideDown(); with $(this).find("ul").slideDown(); The "this" keyword references the particular worksList h2, travels down its chain to find attached ul's. 

$(".worksList h2").click(function() {
 $(this).find("ul").slideDown();
 ...
});